# Place 15 seconds delay in a jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a script that closes an iframe after a click it.
I need that when you click on the link inside the iframe has delay 15 seconds to load a page within the iframe and after 15 seconds the iframe automatically closes.

```js
   $(window).on('blur',function(e) {    
    if($(this).data('mouseIn') != 'yes')return;
    $('iframe').filter(function(){
     return $(this).data('mouseIn') == 'yes';
    }).trigger('iframeclick');    
   });

   $(window).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'no');
   });

   $('iframe').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
    $(window).data('mouseIn', 'yes');
   }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).data('mouseIn', null);
   });

   $('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
                $(this).hide()
   });

   $('<input type="text" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;height:0px;width:0px;"/>').appendTo(document.body).blur(function(){
     $(window).trigger('blur');
    }).focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe style="width:400px;
height:250px;" src="//example.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sleep () function and solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to Jquery you can use .delay()

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

To wait 15 seconds before the iframe close, you should do this :

```
$('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
                $(this).delay(15000).hide();
}
```

In a simple way, you put a delay of 15s before the "hide" action

Comment: How do I implement it in my script? I'm not good with JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented in my script but does not work. Did I do something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/g40bf0f4/

Comment: @AxelCardinaels that is invalid JavaScript syntax `15000ms`

Comment: @Murilo, remove the ms at the end of the duration, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the setTimeout() method. You can find how to use it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp.

In your case would be something like (this can be optimized, take out global var etc.):

```
 globalVar = null;
 function closeIframe() {
     globalVar.hide();
 }
 $('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
      globalVar = $(this);
      setTimeout("closeIframe()", 15000);
 });
```

Comment: How do I implement it in my script? I'm not good with JavaScript

Comment: Could put an example of this script running in jsFiddle. Please

Comment: Why did you use `setTimeout("closeIframe()", 15000);` instead of `setTimeout(closeIframe, 15000);`? it's better practice and less code

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER EVER pass a string to `setTimeout`!

Answer (score 0):

Use good old [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
var timeoutValue = 15000; /*ms*/
setTimeout(function(){...}, timeoutValue);
```

which in you case could look like:

```
var close = function(element){element.hide();};
$('iframe').on('iframeclick', function(){
  var timeoutValue = 15000;
  var context = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){close(context)}, timeoutValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding event listeners to elements inside the iframe will **only work if both the parent site and the iframe are on the same domain**. If the contents of the iframe is on a different domain, you won't be able to perform this as it is classed as "click-jacking", which is a big security threat. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

If the iframe is on the same domain then you can add the event listener inside the iframe and then call the parent to notify the event.

You can also grab the contents and find the element you want to bind the event handler on.

```
$("iframe#name").contents().find(".link").on("click", function() {
    $("iframe#name").delay(15000).hide();
});
```

Related:

- [How to add click event to a iframe with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609741/how-to-add-click-event-to-a-iframe-with-jquery)
- [Click-event on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572227/click-event-on-iframe)
- [Bind to events inside dynamically created iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088057/bind-to-events-inside-dynamically-created-iframe)
- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- [Detect click inside iframe (same domain/sub domain) in Chrome using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477917/detect-click-inside-iframe-same-domain-sub-domain-in-chrome-using-jquery)